# How can I print an array via pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

Our teacher gave this code and we need to get this code operational.

How can I print the values inside of array?

```
cout << wizardsCollection->birthYear;
```

is returns what I gave but *wizardsCollection->nameSurname* returns empty value.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
struct Wizard {
    string nameSurname;
    int birthYear;
    string hairColour;
};

struct Wizard *createWizards() {
    Wizard wizardsCollection[3];

    for (int index = 0; index < *(&wizardsCollection + 1) - wizardsCollection; index = index + 1) {
        wizardsCollection[index].nameSurname = "Name and surname of " + index;
        wizardsCollection[index].birthYear = 0;
        wizardsCollection[index].hairColour = "Hair colour of " + index;
    }

    return wizardsCollection;
}

int main()
{
    Wizard *wizardsCollection = createWizards();
    cout << wizardsCollection->nameSurname;
}
```

Comment: I recommend [enabling your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/eEbnsxMnq).  It will also help your question if you can explain what "I can't [print]" and "not working" means.

Comment: _Please don't give me bad comment.

I want to print all values of array but I can't."_ well i'll give you _"bad comment"_: What's actually happening? You're unclear as can be. Voted to close, downvoted.

Comment: I can't find enough resources on my own language. Also I think my English not enough for find resources.

Comment: You cannot return an array in C++. The array [will decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) and then go out of scope leaving the program with a pointer to an invalid object. Using that pointer to access the invalid object [could do anything](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and in this case that anything is an empty string. You could also get exactly what you expected, making it hard to spot the mistake sometimes, or [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These books are all in English and the links are to English versions, but you should find many of them translated to a wide variety of other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a huge problem here. `wizardsCollection` is created on the stack.  As soon as the function returns, that stack memory goes away.  Your pointer will be pointing into empty space.  You need to use a std::vector for this, to manage the memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Wizard {
    std::string nameSurname;
    int birthYear;
    std::string hairColour;
};

void createWizards(std::vector<Wizard> & wizardsCollection) {
    wizardsCollection.clear();
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++ ) {
        wizardsCollection.push_back(Wizard({
            "Name and surname of " + std::to_string(index),
            0,
            "Hair colour of " + std::to_string(index)
        }));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Wizard> wizardsCollection;
    createWizards(wizardsCollection);
    std::cout << wizardsCollection[0].nameSurname << "\n";
}
```

There are other ways to do it, but this models what you had.

Comment: [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) would also be returned correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Thank you so much again, Tim. I already found a solution but your method looks like better than mine. I will use your method.